# python handling of memory

Tags: python, memory, operating-system

I've noticed that Python handles memory in a way that I didn't expect. I have a huge data set which is stored in a 70 GB file. I usually load this file with `np.loadtxt()` and do some math on that. I have 32 GB of RAM and I've noticed that, when loaded into memory, around 25 GB of RAM is used. But apparently, this value can change. For example once, while I was processing the data, I got a memory error. After the error the dataset was still in the memory, I verified that I could access it, but only around 5 GB of RAM were used. How is this possible? And how can I force python to use as less memory as possible with my data so that I can run other application simultaneously? 
Moreover, sometimes I do calculations which return a new dataset as large as the original, so that at the end I've a number of large dataset in memory, but the total used RAM is not changed. Are these variables written on the hard disk in some way? If so, why sometimes I get memory crashes? 
(BTW I use spyder as IDE if it matters)

Comment: This is what your algorithms should be written to work with streams of data, so you don't need to load the entire dataset into memory at once. There are a lot of factors in play here, involving Python garbage collection, and OS virtual memory and swapping.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: the OP is using [`np.loadtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html), so it's not his algorithm

Comment: You may want to look at `numpy.memmap()` if you want to access just parts of your file http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Comment: The operating system decides how much RAM to use, Python uses virtual memory, not real memory.  Much of the memory used could well be on a swap area (or pagefile, depending on the OS) on disk.   How much resides in RAM, and when, depends on lots of other things, not least what other processes are doing on the machine.